# “Include file not found” error on IIS (Windows 11)

Tags: iis, asp-classic, include, windows-11

I have been running a data server based on IIS/ASP/SQLServer for a few years on my old PC (hereafter PC1) now running Windows 10 and too old to move on to Windows 11. The ASP code files and shared library files  are located in folders code and lib, respectively, both of which under the site's root directory. The code files in folder code start with the directive <!— #include virtual=“/lib/library.asp” —> and it all works fine.

I have now got a new PC (hereafter PC2) running Windows 11 and am attempting to transfer the data server to this new device. I have installed IIS on PC2, imported the code and library files with the same folder structure as on PC1 and ensured that all Windows Features and IIS Settings on PC2 match those on PC1. However, when I call up an asp page on PC2, I get the error message “Include file not found”.

I have tried various approaches suggested in on-line user groups, such as setting the IIS parameter EnableParentPaths to True or selecting ServerSideIncludes under Windows features, but none of these worked (and none of these required on PC1). I have checked permissions to the library folder but found them (as expected) to be identical to those of the code folder.

I can’t understand why I get a different behaviour on PC1 and PC2 when all settings are identical (bar the fact that they run different versions of Windows and therefore IIS). Unless I missed out a well-hidden setting somewhere out of IIS and Windows Features?
I am running out of ideas to sort this out. Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Maybe some companies out there are paying a lot to keep some classic ASP programmers, but you rarely see any other out here because that product has been marked deprecated for more than two decades.

Comment: @LexLi and yet Microsoft still support it in IIS. I regularly still support multiple Classic ASP sites so not that rare.

Comment: Did you make sure to install Server Side Includes as part of the IIS installation?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If it is convenient, I suggest you write the solution as an answer and post it instead of editing the answer in the question body. Your answer will help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. Yes SSI is installed and yes I should move away from ASP, but the learning curve is steep and I need to get this working first.

I have actually stumbled on the answer by accident: I had restarted the site on IIS after the various changes but I hadn't restarted the PC. Doing so seems to have solved the problem, as I am now through. How stupid of me not to have figured this out earlier! Lesson learnt.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. If you can click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered, it will lead more people in the right direction.

Comment: @YurongDai Lead people to restart their machines you mean - Computers 101. If something isn't working, restart the machine.